# spring security is authenticating all requests even though they are permitted

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I configured my spring security as below and both endpoints `/123` and `/asfsadf` are not being ignored. Any idea on this?

Thank you for your time

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Value("${URL_PREFIX}")
    private String url_prefix;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/123").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/asfsadf");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // Get AuthenticationManager bean
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


}
```

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    @Autowired
    private UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(httpServletRequest);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {

                int userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserById(userId);

                if(userDetails != null) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                            authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                }
            }
            else{
                Map<String, ArrayList<String>> responseBody = new HashMap<>();

                responseBody.put("errors", new ArrayList<>(List.of("Failed to authenticate.")));

                httpServletResponse.setStatus(UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                httpServletResponse.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                new ObjectMapper().writeValue(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.info(ex.getMessage());
            Map<String, ArrayList<String>> responseBody = new HashMap<>();

            responseBody.put("errors", new ArrayList<>(List.of(ex.getMessage())));

            httpServletResponse.setStatus(UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            httpServletResponse.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
            new ObjectMapper().writeValue(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private String getJwtFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class JwtTokenProvider {
    @Value("${JWT_SECRET}")
    private String JWT_SECRET;

    @Value("${ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRATION}")
    private long ACCESS_JWT_EXPIRATION;

    @Value("${REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION}")
    private long REFRESH_JWT_EXPIRATION;

    public String generateAccessToken(CustomUserDetails userDetails) {
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + ACCESS_JWT_EXPIRATION);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(userDetails.getUser().getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, JWT_SECRET)
                .compact();
    }

    public String generateRefreshToken(CustomUserDetails userDetails){
        Date now = new Date();
        Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + REFRESH_JWT_EXPIRATION);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(Long.toString(userDetails.getUser().getId()))
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(expiryDate)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, JWT_SECRET)
                .compact();
    }

    public int getUserIdFromJWT(String token) {
        Claims claims = Jwts.parser()
                .setSigningKey(JWT_SECRET)
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();

        return Integer.parseInt(claims.getSubject());
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token){
        try{
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(JWT_SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);

            return true;
        } catch (MalformedJwtException ex) {
            log.error("Invalid JWT token");
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException ex) {
            log.error("Expired JWT token");
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException ex) {
            log.error("Unsupported JWT token");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            log.error("JWT claims string is empty.");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a custom JWTfilter when there is already built in one in spring security that you can customize? Whats the purpose of using a security framework if you dont intend to use it?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about the built in one. I'll go take a look and try it

Comment: But beside that, I noticed that even though I have permitted an endpoint but whenever I request it, the JWTFilter will always be called. Aren't the permitted endpoint supposed to be processed without going through the JWTfilter?

Comment: there is an entire chapter in the spring security reference about JWT authentication https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture you can basically remove your entire filter, and all you do is build set or expose a `decoder` as a bean and it will get injected into the spring security jwt filter https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-decoder-dsl

Comment: Thank you very much. I have just learned spring security for like 2 days and I definitely need to spend more time on it.

Comment: As mentioned above, it's recommended to use `oauth2-resource-server` support which can be configured to validate JWTs. But based on your posted code, it looks like you've registered your filter twice by using `@Bean`. Try removing `@Bean` from your filter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JWT Authentication Filter will be called for **all** public and protected requests.

For endpoints that are supposed to be authenticated, the J`WTAuthenticationFilter` will expect the JWT to be passed in the request (eg: Authorization Header).
The token passed in then validated thoroughly and this filter then sets an authentication object inside the `SecurityContextHolder`.

In case of public requests(the ones that are permitted and not to be authenticated), the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` will still be called, however, since this public(or permitted) endpoint will not have a JWT passed in the request, the JWTAuthenticationFilter will not do anything, It will simply pass on the request to the filters down in the FilterChain.

```
   filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);//continue applying other filters
```

In case you do not send a JWT for a protected endpoint, the  `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` (which is a built-in filter from Spring Security) fails the authentication. However, the same filter is not called when the endpoint is public.

I believe the reason why JWTAuthenticationFilter is called for all endpoints also depends on its position in the FilterChain.

```
   http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

**Edit:**
Your code

```
     else{
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> responseBody = new HashMap<>();

        responseBody.put("errors", new ArrayList<>(List.of("Failed to authenticate.")));

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(UNAUTHORIZED.value());
        httpServletResponse.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        new ObjectMapper().writeValue(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
    }
```

should be removed. If `userDetails` is null, then the `SecurityContextHolder` will not be populated, and leave the job of failing the authentication to the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter`. You do not need the else block.  Remove the try-catch as well. Let Spring Security take care of any exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've been trying many different solutions and this came to my mind. It seems to get the work done.

But this is not a good way because there's already a built in JWTFilter in spring security, thanks to @Toerktumlare. You can find the link to the document in his comment above.

```
@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(httpServletRequest.getServletPath().equals("/api/v1/login")){
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
        else{
            try {
                String jwt = getJwtFromRequest(httpServletRequest);

                if (StringUtils.hasText(jwt) && tokenProvider.validateToken(jwt)) {

                    int userId = tokenProvider.getUserIdFromJWT(jwt);

                    UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserById(userId);

                    if (userDetails != null) {
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                                authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpServletRequest));

                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
                    }
                } else {
                    Map<String, ArrayList<String>> responseBody = new HashMap<>();

                    responseBody.put("errors", new ArrayList<>(List.of("Failed to authenticate.")));

                    httpServletResponse.setStatus(UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                    httpServletResponse.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.info(ex.getMessage());
                Map<String, ArrayList<String>> responseBody = new HashMap<>();

                responseBody.put("errors", new ArrayList<>(List.of(ex.getMessage())));

                httpServletResponse.setStatus(UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                httpServletResponse.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                new ObjectMapper().writeValue(httpServletResponse.getOutputStream(), responseBody);
            }

            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }

    }
```

However, I still don't understand, isn't it supposed to be that permitted endpoints will be processed without going through the JWTAuthFilter.

Comment: please do not upload images of code, it is against the rules read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I'll edit it